# VNC on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vnc

Has anyone gotten VNC on Windows Server 2008 R2 to work?

Comment: I use VNC often, but not on my Server 2008 development machines, because one must pay for the enterprise license for vista-based operating systems and up - thus I tend to use Remote Desktop over VPN for win2k8+

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use VNC?!

Comment: I had it installed on a VM running Server 08 R2. Could you inform us of the issues you're having by editing your original post?

Comment: This question has been passed around the stackoverflow network: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662204/vnc-on-windows-server-2008-r2 and http://superuser.com/questions/64499/vnc-on-windows-server-2008-r2
Yes, someone has. Which VNC are you talking about specifically and what are your difficulties with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**  I just installed [Real VNC](http://www.realvnc.com) on my Windows 2008 **R2** server 4 weeks ago.  It worked just fine for me.

Note: you'll require the **Personal Edition** (or better) for Windows Server 2008 support.  The **Free Edition** doesn't support Windows Server 2008.  See http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like UltraVNC 1.0.8.0 works with Windows Server 2008 R2 and it's free.  Version 1.0.6.5 did not work.  See http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?t=16410

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the client or the server?

The client should work just fine.

If you're talking about the server... why? Just... why?

Comment: Doesn't MS charge you extra beyond a certain number of Remote Desktop licenses per server?  (They did in win2k3...)

Comment: @Kev: Yes, if you're going to use it as a terminal server (more than two concurrent connections), you'll need additional licenses. But VNC will anyway only let you connect to the console session, so it's of no use here. BTW, in my opinion it's of no use *anyway*.

Answer (score 0):

TightVNC should also work see:
http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html